# Api Integration using Oauth1.0 in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, authentication, oauth

```
app.post('/Addbus',function(req,res){   
 request('http://api.seatseller.travel/sources?oauth_consumer_key=************&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1513139815&oauth_nonce=G7Ni53&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=rqYqPAGRRaJhOD2SSDelqnnIhS8=',
 function (error, response) {    
      if (!error) {    
          var x1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));    
          res.json(x1);    
         }    
   })   
});
```

here im giving the `oauth_signature_method` and timestamp statically, how to give the values dynamically.

Comment: Is it pure NodeJS code or you're using Express or SailsJS as framework? Consider taking these things from a configuration file.

Comment: im using express js

Comment: Check out this module: [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) this will help you manage your configuration files.